# #2002 - No such file or directory no phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, osx, mamp

Estou utilizando o MAC OS Sierra (safari 10.0.3), MAMP 4.0.6, phpMyAdmin e netBeans.

Tudo ia muito bem, já havia rodado a aplicação alguma vezes até que do nada o computador travou.

Reiniciei o laptop e quando eu abri o MAMP novamente a indicação do MySql server não fica verde igual a do Apache Server (o normal é os dois ficarem). Abrindo o Safari, digitando **localhost/phpmyadmin**, como eu sempre fiz e dava certo, passou a informar

> 0 #2002 - No such file or directory - O servidor não está a responder (ou o socket do servidor local está mal configurado).

Isso já aconteceu antes, resolvi instalando MAMP novamente, porém tive que criar novamente o BD e as respectivas tabelas no phpMyAdmin, o que deu muito trabalho e não gostaria de ter que fazer novamente, até porque receio que o problema volte a ocorrer.

Fiz algumas pesquisas na internet, encontrei soluções para problemas parecidos, mas não exatamente iguais a este, mas tentei aplicá-las e não funcionou.

Eu gostaria de alguma solução em que não seja preciso reinstalar o MAMP.

Comment: É provável que a porta do mysql server esteja em uso por outro processo.

Comment: Fiz essa pesquisa... Nada! Nenhuma porta sendo utilizada...